# How can I use pointers to access the elements of this two-dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a two dimensional array as follows:
char board[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

and I'm accessing its elements as follows:

```
cout << board[0][0] << board[0][1] << board[0][2] << "\n";
cout << board[1][0] << board[1][1] << board[1][2] << "\n";
cout << board[2][0] << board[2][1] << board[2][2] << "\n";
```

Now I'd want to create a pointer to this array and access its elements. So here's what I came up with: `char (*ptr)[3] = board`    which doesn't work.

How to access the elements using pointers?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? It seems fine to me: https://godbolt.org/z/oco4fExjj

Comment: As you've described it,   `ptr[i][j]` will access `board[i][j]`   (assuming `i` and `j` are valid indices, i.e. between `0` and `2` inclusive).    If you expect something different, you need to specify what you expect.

Comment: So, I need to access the elements without utilizing brackets. For example, I'm still using array brackets to get the elements such as (ptr)[0][0] for 1 and (ptr)[0][1] for 2...

Comment: @ArmeenParsa the `[ ]` operator is also used for indexing from a pointer. It's not clear what you mean by "without using brackets" .  You can use the transformation `a[b]` <--> `*((a) + (b))`

Comment: You don't need braces around `ptr`.   Thanks to order of precedence  `(ptr)[i][j]` and `ptr[i][j]` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to give a generalized answer :

like imagine if you have an multidimensional integer array :

```
int arr[3][3] = {{2,1,2}, {3,4,6}, {2,1,9}};
```

here . there are 3 rows and 3 columns [3][3].
you might want to know them (size of array, rows and columns) at least in this method.There is one more method that can be used but i am sure, it will go out of scope.

So,

the way you access every element with pointer is :

```
 for(int *iter = &arr[0][0]; iter != &arr[0][0] + 3 * 3; iter++){
    std::cout << * (iter) << "  " ;
  }
```

`*iter = &arr[0][0]` here we are assigning it to the first element and the condition is sert to `iter != &arr[0][0] + 3 * 3` here as i knew size is 3 rows 3 columns so i did this , you can do `+ rows * columns;` that would work.

```
Optiplex@jetta:~/Desktop/PROGRAM/CPP$ ./b.out
2  1  2  3  4  6  2  1  9
```

here is the output for you.

Similarly, will do for the character,

CODE FOR CHARACTER :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
  
  char BOARD[3][3] = {{'1', '2', '3'}, {'4', '5', '6'}, {'7', '8', '9'}};

  for(char * iter = &BOARD[0][0]; iter != &BOARD[0][0] + 3 * 3; iter++){
    std::cout << * (iter) << "  " ;
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :

```
Optiplex@jetta:~/Desktop/PROGRAM/CP$ ./b.out
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

we have used iter as pointer . and iter is kinda abbreviation for iterator (because you are using it to iterate through your array, its nice to name your variables conviently).
I hope i helped you, if there is something left please let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm curious whether I can get to the elements without using the for-loop at all. Can I?

Comment: @ArmeenParsa You can do it obviously, a loop is just an automated task which is done repetitively, you can do it manually by increasing the iter, do you see that iter++? in the loop?. thats it. that does the job for you. if you did it manually you have to do it iter = iter + 1; and it will jump to the next element in the array, as arrays are stored sequentially , it will jump to the next right element. still any doubt , feel free to ask

Comment: So like board[1] would be *(ptr + 1). Then what about board[1][1]. Sorry, it's kinda hard for me...

Comment: yes  if *iter = &BOARD[0][0];

*(iter + 1) = 2

*(iter + 4) = 5 

*(iter + 2) = 3




(actually there are sooo many methods that can be used there is even a double pointer method , but you have to study about that, i wont recommend jumping to it directly , if you still want it, its  very easy to find just google multidimensional pointer arithmetic.